# RAM too close to heatsink?

Tags: memory, heatsink

So I'm in the middle of building a new NAS and I've got most of it put together already.  I'm  keep thinking about my RAM and proximity to the heatsink.  The RAM is barely touching but very close to the heatsink.  RAM also has a heat spread / heat sink.

Should I worry?  I only have one 8gb stick.  I could just move it over to the 3rd position but wondering if I should care

Comment: Your RAM heat sink should not be touching the CPU heatsink. Why not move it? You want maximum air flow around all heatsinks, right?

Comment: You're building your own, so you should know this: do you have a fan which blows air over the CPU? In which direction? It's no problem at all if the cool air heading _to_ the CPU passes the RAM, that's just efficient.

Comment: The below is what I got so it points up.  There is a front fan but I sort of feel like I made a mistake with the heatsink because I could have fit something bigger.

http://www.amazon.com/Noctua-Low-Profile-Cooler-Retail-Cooling/dp/B009VCAJ7W/ref=sr_1_8?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1402102421&sr=1-8&keywords=noctua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to overheat RAM. As long as you run your RAM at the vendors specified voltage temps won't be an issue. In example [Samsung recommends](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/product/computing-dram/catalogue?iaId=693&CID=AFL-hq-mul-0813-11000279):

```
C : Commercial, Normal (0°C ~ 85°C)
L : Commercial, Low (0°C ~ 85°C)
```

Having in mind that when CPU radiator temperature reaches 85°C the ram is the last issue as the CPU will probably be overheated and damaged.

Comment: Yes, especially if RAM is 8GB. You will need heatsink if RAM is bigger/faster (e.g. 128GB at 2133MHZ).

Comment: Ok thanks guys.  I'll go ahead and leave it as is.